# decode file stream in savon client

Tags: attachment, savon

I have a file stream generated by .xlsm file as savon response ruby. How do I decode or convert the stream and save it to file_name.xlsm?

@body=
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">http://tempuri.org/\">212706.0_PCT.xlsmhttp://tempuri.org/\">UEsDBBQABgAIAFs+Lk1un6t7iQIAAMkWAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...........

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Nokogiri` gem to extract the content from the element in `@body`. Then use `Base64.decode64()` to convert the data into binary and finally write it to a file.

Comment: Thank you Steffen Roller. It worked after decoding, Base64.decode64(file_stream).force_encoding('UTF-8')

Comment: @DalRai Please accept my answer and/or upvote it :-)